How to check if a file can be opened from external app using a package in Flutter?
I am using the open_filex package in Flutter to facilitate the opening of various file formats on Android. While some file types, like images, can be accessed through default Android apps like Gallery, others, such as ZIP files, may not open without a supporting external app. When executing OpenFile.open(path) on a ZIP file without an external app that supports , no message is given that the file cannot be opened. However, with a compatible external app for ZIP files installed, the file opens successfully. My problem is not limited to ZIP files but also to other file extensions. Is there a method for programmatically determining whether a given file extension can be opened by an external app or any alternative package that best supports my problem?
The open_filex package allows the opening of files with any file extension. I want to be able to open a file using an external app that supports the file or to inform the user that the file cannot be opened.
